# How to create slug of many to many fields in django?

Tags: django, django-models, model, many-to-many, slug

I want to make slugs on post save for my model using three fields one charfield and two ManytoMany Fields but getting error during saving.
Here is my code:

### Heading ##class product(models.Model):

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
image = models.ForeignKey(all_images, verbose_name='Product Images', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='proimages')
ProductName = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False,default="None", blank=False,verbose_name="Product Name")
CategoryName = models.ManyToManyField(category,related_name='procat', blank=False,verbose_name="Category Name")
SubcatName = models.ManyToManyField(subcategory,related_name='prosubcat', blank=False,verbose_name="Sub-category Name")

description = RichTextUploadingField(blank= False,verbose_name="Description")
price = models.IntegerField(default=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Price')

slug = models.SlugField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)


def get_slug(self):
    slug = self.ProductName
    try:
        for items in self.SubcatName.all():
            slug +=items.name
        try:
            for items in self.CategoryName.all():
                slug +=items.CategoryName
        except:
            pass
    except:
        pass
    return slugify(slug)
```

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

```
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = self.get_slug()
    super(product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace of the error you're getting?

Comment: "<product: try slug>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.